What to do with cross site questions
There is an example

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2910433/key-space-for-a-restricted-substitution-cipher
Keys-space for a restricted substitution cipher

These two questions are posted from the same person.
There are two cases;

It is noticed early and can be closed immediately.
As, in this case, they lived and answered.

What to do with the second case?

There is a well-established policy on SE, which says:
If it is on-topic on both sides, cross-link for the added information, but otherwise treat it like any other question.
The only special behavior I can imagine here is that if the question could be migrated but already exists on the target site, then it should be merely closed (to avoid the target site having to close it as a duplicate).

This SE FAQ post seems like a clearer indication of established policy, and paints a much more negative picture. (The accepted answer starts with a big "NO.") That said, there does seem to be some legitimate variation in opinions; probably the most that can be definitely said is that it's strongly discouraged, but in practice sometimes accepted.
